# Trouble with Vue methods

Tags: vue.js, methods, hover

doing some Vue.js challenges for school and having trouble with a function that should trigger on a hover.
I need the div with the class 'redBox' to grow 10 pixels taller each time it is hovered over.

Here's my code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>v-on Event Handlers</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <style>
        .box{width:200px; height:200px; background:green; border:2px solid black; text-align:center; line-height:200px; color:white;}
        .hidden{display:none;}
        .redBox{width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: red; margin: 2em;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="app">
    <div v-bind:class="{box:true, hidden:boxHidden}">{{message}}</div>
    <button v-on:click="showhide();">{{buttonText}}</button>
    <div class="redBox" v-on:hover="hoverGrow();"></div>
</div>

<script>
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    
    data:{
        boxHeight:200,
        boxHidden : false,
        message  : 'Make me disappear!',
        buttonText : "Hide",
        hovered: false,
    },
    methods:{
        showhide : function(){
            console.log(this.boxHidden);
            if(this.boxHidden){
                this.boxHidden=false;
                this.buttonText="Hide";
            }else{
                this.boxHidden=true;
                this.buttonText="Show"; 
            }
        },
        hoverBox : function(){
            this.boxHeight = boxHeight + 10;
        }
    }
    
});
```

Any tips as to why this doesn't work?  Right now nothing happens when I hover over the square.

Answer (score 0):

Try using v-on:mouseover instead of v-on:hover. Also your function appears to be named hoverBox not hoverGrow. So v-on:mouseover="hoverBox();" should work in your redBox div.